# How can I change a Facebook post using JavaScript while in editing mode?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I want to change the content of a Facebook post in editing mode.

[image]

What I expect is that after selecting the text in editing mode, I can modify it using JavaScript.

The HTML code of facebook post is like.

```
<div aria-label="What's on your mind, ?" class="xzsf02u x1a2a7pz x1n2onr6 x14wi4xw x9f619 x1lliihq x5yr21d xh8yej3 notranslate" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" style="user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; font-size: 24px;" data-lexical-editor="true">
  <p class="xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x16tdsg8 xdpxx8g" dir="ltr">
    <span data-lexical-text="true">Change this text with js while in editing mode.
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

I attempted to replicate the code in a local environment and was able to modify the text using JavaScript, as shown below

```
let selection = window.getSelection();

let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

let selectedText = range.toString();
let newText = selectedText.split('Change').join('CHANGE!!!');

let newNode = document.createTextNode(newText);

range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(newNode);
```

However, I was unable to modify the content of the Facebook post using the same code. The code only deletes the first line of content in my post, and the range.insertNode(newNode) function does not insert any text.

I suspect that Facebook has disabled some JavaScript effects, but I am uncertain about how to debug this issue.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible, you should be using `Puppeteer` and fake remove text and typing content.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).